# Safely storing hydrogen

Tags: safety, hydrogen

I have built a solar panel which is used to add electrodes to $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{NaCl}$, evolving $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{O2}$.

How can I safely store the hydrogen in the long-term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hydrogen can't and won't explode as long as it is kept separate from oxygen, unless you're storing it under high pressure.  So as long as your hydrogen container can't break or leak under all sorts of environmental hazards (heat, fire, dropping, collision, degradation, etc.), you should be fine.  Essentially, this question is more about risk management to consider all the possible scenarios of a potential leak.

Ultimately it depends on how and where you will store your hydrogen container, and the potential dangers of that environment.  So storing hydrogen under low pressure within an argon-filled safe would be a lot safer than storing it under high pressure in a mobile oxygen tent.

Comment: So you are saying hydrogen becomes flammable when coming in contact with oxygen? meaning if it comes in contact with H2O the excess Hydrogen will ignite? THAT IS EXTREMELY USEFUL TO KNOW! I am looking into argon now.

Comment: Obviously you misunderstood.  I wasn't talking about the Water substance being ignited. I was more over talking about https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdxi-PvNYS8 again, my question was a safe way on storing hydrogen without the risk of ignition, ie. Oxygen, tempature ect..

Comment: The video is fake, notice the cut after taking the batteries out, and don't believe everything you see on YouTube. Pay attention to the comments and downvotes.

Comment: @Kelvin While you certainly have a point, we all would appreciate if you could [be nice](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @Kelvin i only google and posted a random video. My point is hydrogen builds up when being split from oxygen from a negative electrode terminal and becomes flammable. ie. Hydrogen gas. i did not watch the video, i have tested this myself, but the results were only a sudden ignition with a loud pop.

Comment: Ok, then how do you separate the hydrogen from the oxygen gas from electrolysis?  In any case you need to remove all oxygen from the hydrogen, and then keep oxygen from mixing back in.  As long as the hydrogen has no oxygen, it cannot ignite - as per my original answer.